# MVC - DropDownList wrong option selected when value from model is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, drop-down-menu, null, selected

I have two DropDownLists in form, both displaying list of regions. First is required, second not, stored as null in db.
When I open the page for edit and first dropdownlist is ie. Region 2, and the second is null, the first option "< not specified >" should be selected in second dropdownlist, but the same option as in first dropdownlist is selected.
When I check for null in controller and set the property to value, which is not in the dropdownlist, ie. -1, it selects corrects first option "< not specified >".

Is there a way to recieve the first option selected, when the model value for this dropdown is null ?

kubiix

Comment: let's see your code!, the model, the view code, all that stuff!

Comment: More specifically from Patricia's comment, please show us how you're instancing the `SelectList()`s that you're binding the controls against.

Comment: I suspect that you use non-nullable int for your `Region` properties. When value-type property receives null it'll be substituted with the default value, in this case 0. And I'm assuming that your element at 0 index is what you get. I might be wrong, it's one of the possibilities.